# Postgres full text search (tsvector / tsquery) not behaving as expected

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

[This article](https://www.compose.com/articles/mastering-postgresql-tools-full-text-search-and-phrase-search/) has the following example:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog')  
  @@ to_tsquery('jumping');
```

(note: I had to add `'english'` for it to work properly at all)

They claim this returns a `true` value. However, I get `false`. Even if I query for `'jumped'`, it returns `false`!

Another test I ran that should've returned a `true` value:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'Markets Officer bandwidth') @@ to_tsquery('officer');
```

This returned `false`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: the examples are correct. you have some misconfiguration of FTS.

Comment: @ИгорьТыра What would be misconfigured, specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Aha! This works:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog')  
  @@ to_tsquery('english', 'jumping');
```

Comment: so.. ```to_tsquery``` syntax seems to be postgresql version dependent. i tried your examples on ```11.6``` and they gave ```true```

Comment: It sounds like your default_text_search_config  is not set to 'english', which the example assumes.

Comment: @jjanes Not sure how to change it. I tried `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'` but it didn't work.

Comment: I just always specify the config explicitly each time I use one of those functions, as that seems cleaner than having it set implicitly.  But the command you show should work but it won't take effect until the next time you log in to dbname.

Comment: This answer saved me with a similar issue django after using a SearchQuery to filter by a SearchVectorField that had `language` specified, where you have to set the `config` parameter in `SearchQuery` to the same value. Hopefully this helps someone else 